# How is the right map found in order to show a group is isomorphic to another?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For example, I have the group $\operatorname{GL}(n;\mathbb{R})/\operatorname{GL}^{+}(n;\mathbb{R})$ where $\operatorname{GL}^{+}(n;\mathbb{R})=\{A \in \operatorname{GL}(n;\mathbb{R}): \det(A)>0\}$ and I need to determine the group to which it is isomorphic to. Using the homomorphism this should be the image of a map but I am unable to find the map. What should i consider whilst trying to find this map ?

Comment: Do you have any suspicions as to what the quotient group is isomorphic to?

Comment: is it the inner automorphism of G ?

Answer (score 4):

An idea for you to check:

What about

$$\phi: GL_n(\Bbb R)\to \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;,\;\;\phi A:=\begin{cases}0\pmod 2,&\det A>0\\{}\\1\pmod 2,&\det A<0\end{cases}\;\;\;?$$

Much more important than the above is: how in the world did I (or anyone else) could even begin to think in such a possibility (which, so far, could be wrong or right. That's not the point now) ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly my question actually how do you think to come up with this possibility ?

Comment: @April: We need a map (group homomorphism) with a massive kernel: all the matrices with **positive** determinant. One has to check first, of course, this set is indeed a subgroup. But then this leads you to think of the set of all matrices with *negative* determinant, and how the product between elements here, and with the first set, behaves and etc...

Comment: Would you be able to give me a general approach to find the right map ?

Comment: @aprilanalysis I thought I did in the above...there is not, as far as I know, general approach for **any** general such question. One has to check and understand the given data, imo